# How can I pass a function parameter as an attribute of a module in python?

Tags: python, hashlib

```
def hash(malware, hash):

        h = hashlib.hash()
        with open(malware,'rb') as f:
            chunk = 0
            while chunk != b'':
                chunk = f.read(1024)
                h.update(chunk)
        return h.hexdigest()

hash(file, 'sha1')
hash(file, 'sha256')
```

What I'm trying to do is use the attributes "sha1" and "sha256" of the hashlib module as function parameters.

Is that even possible or is there a way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `hash` as name for your function, because it is built-in function from standard library.
On your question - import the hash functions you want from `hashlib` and pass them as objects, not `str`

```
from hashlib import sha1, sha256


def myhash(malware, hashfunc):

        h = hashfunc()
        with open(malware,'rb') as f:
            chunk = 0
            while chunk != b'':
                chunk = f.read(1024)
                h.update(chunk)
        return h.hexdigest()

myhash(file, sha1)
myhash(file, sha256)
```

If you insist on using `str`, use `getattr()`

```
import hashlib

def myhash(malware, hashfunc):

        h = getattr(hashlib, hashfunc)()
        with open(malware,'rb') as f:
            chunk = 0
            while chunk != b'':
                chunk = f.read(1024)
                h.update(chunk)
        return h.hexdigest()

myhash(file, 'sha1')
myhash(file, 'sha256')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let change the approach to this way:

```
def hash(malware, h):
    with open(malware,'rb') as f:
        chunk = 0
        while chunk != b'':
            chunk = f.read(1024)
            h.update(chunk)
    return h.hexdigest()

hash1 = hashlib.sha1()
hash256 = hashlib.sha256()
hash(file, hash1)
hash(file, hash256)
```

So, you just pass `_hashlib.HASH` (i.e. `hash1` and `hash256`) through the function parameter. Below is the example of output:

> ```
> >>> # test.txt --> hello world
> >>> hash('test.txt', hash1) 
> '2aae6c35c94fcfb415dbe95f408b9ce91ee846ed'
> >>> hash('test.txt', hash256) 
> '524857d0148721c24e3e7795e19ade0cdcf49f2a4dfbef2f1575d1208fa8c54f'
> ```